# Can connecting to the SQL Server in excel cause Active directory account locks?

Tags: sql-server, excel, azure-active-directory

I've found it convenient to write queries for reports and then connect to my SQL server in Excel, so that the results automatically populate there. However, I've noticed that I've been getting locked out of my account often. At least once a day.

The reason I believe the two may be connected is because with the majority of them, I used Windows Authentication to login. So, my guess is that it tries to login as me each time someone opens a file and fails, causing the account to lock.

Does anyone know if that could be the cause of these lock outs? If this is a cause, is there a way for me to logout permanently on files that I've sent people?

Comment: No very unlikely, that's not how it works. Windows Auth uses the *existing* Kerberos ticket that was created when you logged in to your PC (ie your username and password is not used), so whoever has these Excel files is logging in under their own login. Most likely, someone is hammering an open remote desktop connection with your username. Check the Security Event logs on the DC, that will tell you where it is coming from.

Comment: I have a remote desktop, so maybe I'm the cause of this. lol. But, I'm not an admin in the AD, so I'm not sure that II can see the DC. Thanks by the way!

Comment: You could also check the logs of whichever PC has the open remote connection if you are local admin on there (and you see why open RDC is a huge vulnerability)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you don't have many options unless you unlink the file from your AD account and have everyone download a local copy and then use their credentials. You could also change the group policy lockout threshold (**ONLY ADVISE ON A SERVICE ACCOUNT IN A SEPERATE OU**) but that may cause some SERIOUS security threats. Like I mentioned I would only use a service account in an isolated OU **only** if it came down to it.

Comment: Also yes to your original heading / title connecting to SQL through Excel using AD can cause lockouts. Anything that uses AD as an authentication provider will lock-out according to the GPO for your domain.